# What is Final Event in Event Flow Report generated by Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am currently exploring Google Analytics so that i could use it my site.
When i viewed the event flow report generated for my site, there was something called final event.

**What is final event mean?**

Is it happening because the user closed the tab he is viewing? (or)

the event which occurred before the session expired (or)

Answer (score 0):

It is simply the last event captured in the session.